# Is it possible to get default value when exit an application (Firebase,Android)?

Tags: android, firebase

I have a problem with value from Firebase database which needed to reset as a default value (If user leaves some value that might be because of application's problem [eg. feeding pet command value]). What I would like to ask is -

**Is it possible to automatically set value as a default value when user exit an application?**

Comment: You can easily detect the exit of an application. So use `setValue` to set the default value in your `onDestroy`, `onPause` or `onDestroyView` function.

Comment: @Reaz Murshed What's different between onDestroy and onDestroyView ?

Comment: @ReazMurshed No, you really can't.  1)There is no Applicaiton level onDestroy.  2)The ending of an application is semi-random.  THe framework will kill it for resources when needed.  There's no way to tell that from a user requested exit.  So using the application being destroyed as a signal of anything is a bad idea.  3)If a program terminates abnormally, it won't recieve an onDestroy.  4)onDestroyView has nothing to do with the exiting of an application.  It would have to do with the deallocation of a single fragment.  That doesn't even mean the Activity is done, much less the application.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Should i use onPaused instead of onDestroy because there's a option that user press button to the other page, so The activity life cycle might ended up with onPaused.

Answer (score 0):

Make a firebase child that contains if the user is connected or not.. and then make a firebase cloud function that detects that child onChange ( user is disconnected in your case) and return the value to its default.